Monteverdi - "Lasciatemi morire" - why was everyone omitting the "voi"?

I forgot where I found the PDF, was some free sheet music site.
This line has the words: "E chi volete voi che mi conforte".
At least in the 20th century recordings I found, first, they all seem to sing "e che volete" (not chi), and then, the word "voi" is missing completely, insetad the "te" seems extended. I'm not fluent in Italian, but would that not change the meaning/make it nonsensical?
Why is that? Were there different "drafts" of this piece used in different periods? How is it mostly sung currently, and why the change?
(I found a bunch of different sheets for this, all different makers - they all have it like in the screen shot).
Audio examples:
example 1 - tenor
example 2 - bass
example 3 - mezzo

We can definitely research the history of the piece, but have you tried to already? If so, please edit to show what you found so there's no need to duplicate what you already know. E.g. the first 30" for me established that this aria is from the opera L'Arianna, and while the opera dates from 1608, there are separate catalogue numbers for two versions of the aria, a 1614 one and a 1623 version. I'll stop there for now, but please edit to tell whether you did the same initial investigation.

I have never researched the history of any such work in any capacity, would havr to have ideas where to sensibly begin. Meanwhile I found a youtube channel providing a "karaoke" rendition of the piece, showing sheet, where it is exactly like they sung in the old recordings, including the "che" vs. "chi". But there is no source shown for the sheet music.

This is originally part of a 1608 opera called L’Arianna which is lost apart from this section (Lamento d’Arianna). Here we have two sources. One is a 1614 5-part madrigal setting in Monteverdi’s 6th book of madrigals. This is what your score is based on. Then we also 1623 voice + continuo setting, which I think can be considered as the first published version for this setting.
The second setting is recorded occasionally:



The first setting:



The linked recordings you give seem to be based on a 1894 Schirmer edition. I do not exactly know on what sources this one is based, but editors do sometimes take some liberties. So it might just be that some editor at some point modified this to his liking. It might also be that the Schirmer edition is based on a different source (note that for a long time it was common to not sing exactly what is given in the score, so there might have been common alterations to the notated score). But it is hard to say without more knowledge on what sources Schirmer used.
Also keep in mind that a 1894 edition of such a score is most probably a modern interpretation, as the interest for HIP only rose mid 20th century. The recordings you’ve given are all quite old, and thus might not even have had access to the original sources. And modern singers will still often use the old editions, because they might have them available, because there is no available modern edition, because accompanists do not want to set their own continuo, because the “incorrect” version is what people know ...

The 1614 madrigal Tenor part does indeed have the word, so it can only be an editorial error (or deliberate meddling!) in whatever published version was used.


The other parts from this version might have lacked the word, though -- I haven't yet had time to look at it myself.  Editorial errors in these movable-type publications were fairly common.

beside the missing word there is also "che volete" instead of "chi...". Both, omitting the "voi" and changing the other must somehow produce something intelligible, at least all the early 20th century Italians singing it didn't seem to mind.
So it being simply an error would seem strange to me, errors often corrupt the meaning or make it sound grammatically broken.

@user1847129 "che volete" means "what do you want"; "chi volete" means "who do you want."  The subject pronoun -- voi -- is optional in Italian, so the change in the text changes the meaning only a little.  But errors that don't change meaning aren't that rare because they can be caused, for example, by a mistake of short-term memory or by sloppy handwriting (along with hasty or nonexistent correction of the proof).  Given the large number of inconsistencies I've seen in these editions I suspect that either or both were common.
